# Adding Gravity Form into Unyson Builder

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress, foreach, associative-array

I am adding Gravity Forms to Unyson builder but problem is the builder only detects/adds the last form title/id.

Here is the code:

```
if ( ! defined( 'FW' ) ) {
    die( 'Forbidden' );
}

$options = array(

    'title' => array(
        'type'  => 'select',
        'value' => 'choice-3',
        'attr'  => array( 'class' => 'custom-class', 'data-foo' => 'bar' ),
        'label' => __('Label', 'fw'),
        'desc'  => __('Description', 'fw'),
        'help'  => __('Help tip', 'fw'),
        'choices' => array(),
    ), // title

); // $options

$forms = GFAPI::get_forms();
foreach ($forms as $form) {
    $form_id = $form['id'];
    $form = GFAPI::get_form( $form_id );
    $form_title = $form['title'];
    $options['title']['choices'] = array(
        $form_id => __($form_title, 'fw'),
    );
}
```

I want to populate the 'choices' array with all the gravity forms titles.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it. after lot of thinking I realized that I should use array_push instead of array in foreach loop. And yes that fixed the problem. Here is the final & working loop:

```
foreach ($forms as $form) {
    $form_id = $form['id'];
    $form = GFAPI::get_form( $form_id );
    $form_title = $form['title'];
    $form_title_value = __($form_title, 'fw');
    array_push( $options['title']['choices'],
    $form_id = $form_title_value );
}
```

array_push() manual: http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-push.php